# Does IE8 line-break on a hyphen?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, wbr

I'm using the `<wbr>` tag to force firefox to line-break when a hyphenated word can't fit in the space remaining on a line (or row), but according to the [quirksmode website](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) IE8 doesn't respect this tag at all.

I can't check for myself, but what would IE8 do with the following markup? Assume that the column is 200px wide, font-size is 16px, and the hyphenated word can't fit .

```
<p>Blah, blah, blah, cloud-<wbr>based environment, blah, blah, blah.</p>
```

Here's an image to make things clearer, showing what happens in FF with and without the `<wbr>` tag.

[image]

I realise that IE8 will ignore the tag, but does it line-break on the hyphen like Chrome and Safari do?

Comment: You should be able to use CSS to style against the `<wbr>` tag, but you would lose the "smart" behavior that is intended.

Comment: Can't you check it by running IE in IE8 mode from developer tools?

Comment: I'm on linux, I can try to find a machine tomorrow where I can check this with my own eyes.

Comment: Also, it appears to be working as intended in IE8-as-IE8 as well as IE8 in quirks mode.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch, that's a very, very good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can check this in Internet Explorer by hitting F12, or by going to Tools > Developer Tools, then changing the Browser Mode and the Document Mode to IE8.

Answer (score 1):

IE treats a hyphen as allowing a line break after it by default. This has been the IE behavior at least since IE 5. If you need to allow a line break in other contexts, then there are several [approaches](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) (which you might use in a combination), such as `<wbr>`, zero width space character, and hyphenation.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's a great article, lots of info.